# ROUTE PARAMETER DISAPPEAR AFTER SAVE DATA

Tags: php, post, laravel-4, url-rewriting, routes

Hi everyone I need help with this problem. I am programming an application using php with laravel framework. My current laravel framework version is 4.2.11

**I have this route to handle POST & GET actions**

```
    Route::any("/myaccount2/ausersave/{code?}", array("as" => "ausersave", 
"uses" => "PrivateController@ausersave"))->before('auth_admin');
```

When I use Get action with `mydomain/myaccount2/ausersave/90`
I get list all data ok. But when I post all data to save the url change to `mydomain/myaccount2/ausersave` (parameter 90 is missing)

I guest this change is before the data is saved because the {code?} or 90 parameter is missing.

So I was looking for a function that allowed my application to post data and keeps the old url `(mydomain/myaccount2/ausersave/90)` 
I find this function Redirect::back() but some post don't recommend to use it

I will apreciate your help. Thanks

My controller function is:

```
public function ausersave($code = 'null') {
$messg = null;
if(Input::get("userid") != null && Input::get("personid") != null) {
return View::make('PrivateController.ausersave', array('message' =>'Ok',
'user' => null, 'children' => null));
}
else if(isset($code)) {
return View::make('PrivateController.ausersave',
$this->ausersaveGet($code) );
}
return View::make('PrivateController.ausersave',
array('message' => '', 'user' => null,
'children' => null));
}
```

$this->ausersaveGet($code) -> this function bring me data form database and return me an array with thosse values array('message' => '', 'user' => $user, 'children' => $children); where user has info about user and children is an array of data. All this data return ok.

Comment: can you please show the code for `PrivateController@ausersave` i.e. how are you trying to pick the the parameter `{code?}`.

Comment: Why you don't separate POST and GET function ? , i think will be easy to maintain. let me know your PrivateController@ausersave code.

Answer (score 0):

I would try taking the the ? out of the route parameter. i.e. change this:

```
Route::any("/myaccount2/ausersave/{code?}", array(......
```

to this:

```
Route::any("/myaccount2/ausersave/{code}", array(......
```

Comment: I guess it is not work because I use ausersave page to insert and update data, so sometimes {code} route parameter will be optional

Comment: but when you take the ? out of the route parameter and then try posting, does the data become available?

Comment: If I taking out the ? It only work for this url mydomain/myaccount2/ausersave/90 but for this url mydomain/myaccount2/ausersave this create an exception

Comment: sure, but does it fix the POST problem? does the `$code` variable contain the POST'ed data?

Comment: Now yes, I put this line in form tag in html side 'url' => URL::full() and now after post data the url keep the {code?} paramtere mydomain/myaccount2/ausersave/90